# Having trouble to position Img opposite of text and at same size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image to be positioned next to a part of text. The text should be positioned on the right hand side and the image on the left hand side parallel with the text. I can get the text on the correct position, but can't seem to get the image positioned very well.

I've been trying to solve this with float and constructing a left-menu and right-menu but to no prevail.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>//ExtendedField\\</title>
    <meta name="fb_admins_meta_tag" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Field-Station"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fieldstation.be/ExtendedField"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Field-Station"/>

    <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="STUDIO_01.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen />
</head>

<h1><a target="title" href="\C:\Users\orint\OneDrive\Documenten\ARCHITECTUUR\06_MICHIEL\06_WEBSITE\00_HTML\02_FIELDSTATION\HOVERTEST_04.html">FS.STUDIO</a></h1>

<body>
<article>
<div class="right-menu"> 
    <ul>
    <li><h1>Hacking the Extended Field.</h1></li>
</div>
<img src="C:\Users\orint\OneDrive\Documenten\ARCHITECTUUR\06_MICHIEL\06_WEBSITE\01_DATABASE\00_Hacking_the_Extended_Field\EXTENDEDFIELDS_COVER.jpg"/ sizes="50vw">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sit amet tortor neque. Donec mollis accumsan venenatis. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas eget nibh quis ante venenatis ultrices. Nulla rhoncus ullamcorper mauris, at blandit nunc accumsan sed. Mauris rhoncus urna vel congue dictum. Nulla facilisi. Nullam consequat purus quis placerat sollicitudin. Vivamus pulvinar fringilla mi, in lacinia libero volutpat quis. Sed pharetra mi viverra, dignissim justo id, vulputate quam. In nec diam eget risus cursus accumsan. Aliquam sed facilisis neque. Nam ac neque sed odio commodo ornare at eget arcu. Duis eu purus dapibus erat tincidunt auctor.</p> 


</article>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
    color: #343639;
    /* font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 44pt;
    line-height: 58pt;*/
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    /*background-color: #f9f9f3;*/
    background-color: #eee;
    /*text-align: left;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*margin-left:auto;*/
    min-width: 300pt;
}

img{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 40vw;
    top: 10vh;
    right: 15vw;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.left-menu,.right-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 0px;
}

.right-menu { 
    right: 0px; 
    text-align: right;
}

.left-menu { 
    left: 0px; 
    text-align: left;
}

.left-menu ul, .right-menu ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.left-menu ul {
    text-align: left;
}

.right-menu ul {
    text-align: right;
}

.left-menu img{
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 70vw;
    height: 40vw;
    top: 10vh;
    right: 15vw;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 50;*/
}

img, video {
    display:Block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-top:10pt;
    margin-bottom:10pt;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

img.desaturate {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

a {
    color:#343639;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#f0eeeb;
    background: #eee;
}

p {
    margin-top: 30pt;
    margin-bottom: 30pt;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 50;
    padding-right:15pt;
    max-width: 400pt;
    min-width: 300pt;
    text-align: justify;
    float:right
}

p.center {
    text-align:right;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    display:block;
    font-size: 35pt;
    margin:20pt;
    margin-bottom:20pt;
    /*margin-left:200pt;*/
    margin-left:30;
    margin-right:30;
    max-width:750pt;
}
```

A parallel positioning of text and image (cf. http://kaleidoscope.media/amnesia-scanner/?fbclid=IwAR3w_8BmSQ91Un6Rsiy0pYO6jnzqYKUIvtzk9iAdmfEvED4jqdLOfQmlmZg , similar to the start of this article as a reference) are the expected results. But i'm seem to get something more like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Sno.jpg

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot! I changed it to relative got it solved eventually. Link had a lot of very informative info on it!